# How to export a tab-separated txt file from php array without quotes

Tags: php, csv, fputcsv

I've managed to save a tab-separated file for a product feed with the code below. However, the feed that I am submitting requires that fields are not encased in quotes. Is there a way to save this file out without quotes in the fields.

```
$feed[]=array('Item','Description','Category');
$feed[]=array('1-1','Words describing item 1, for example.','Top Category > SubCategory1');
$feed[]=array('1-2','Words describing item 2.','Top Category > SubCategory2');

header('Content-type: text/tab-separated-values');
header("Content-Disposition: attachment;filename=bingproductfeed.txt");
$f  =   fopen('php://output', 'a');
foreach ($feed as $fields) {
    //$fields=str_replace('"','',$fields);
    //$fields=trim($fields,'"');
    fputcsv($f, $fields, "\t");
}

//Outputs:
//Item  Description Category
//1-1   "Words describing item 1, for example." "Top Category > SubCategory1"
//1-2   "Words describing item 2."  "Top Category > SubCategory2"

//I need:
//Item  Description Category
//1-1   Words describing item 1, for example.   Top Category > SubCategory1
//1-2   Words describing item 2.    Top Category > SubCategory2
```

I've tried trimming the quotes out and replacing them with spaces, but no luck there. Is there a way to do this so I can submit this feed without errors?

Comment: I would look at "enclosure" ... http://php.net/manual/en/function.fputcsv.php

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on [PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/wrappers.php.php) i'd say you can omit the fopen line and simply echo your output directly on the page.

> php://output ¶
>
> php://output is a write-only stream that allows you to write to the output buffer mechanism in the same way as print and echo.

So something like this:

```
$feed[]=array('Item','Description','Category');
$feed[]=array('1-1','Words describing item 1, for example.','Top Category > SubCategory1');
$feed[]=array('1-2','Words describing item 2.','Top Category > SubCategory2');

header('Content-type: text/tab-separated-values');
header("Content-Disposition: attachment;filename=bingproductfeed.txt");
foreach ($feed as $fields) {
    //$fields=str_replace('"','',$fields);
    //$fields=trim($fields,'"');
    echo implode("\t",$fields);
}
```

Comment: I use a similar method as PHP's built-in CSV functions are buggy when trying to use tabs as delimiters. One thing I'd suggest as an additional safety feature is  to make sure that there are never any tabs left within the field data, which would mess things up. So something like a loop through the data, with ```str_replace("\t", ' ', $field)``` or something similar.